# How to access distanceWalkingAndRunning from HealthKit from watch only?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit, healthkit

I have tried to fetch distance walking and running from health data but instead of what I really walk, it results of both distance from when I use apple watch and when I use my phone. So when I run with both my watch and phone the distance will be doubled.

I would like to take just the distance from watch or even better separate data which I walk with both my phone and my watch.

I have the results but when I sum it, the total distance is not equal to the distance data from Health App.

```
func fetchDistance(endTime: NSDate, startTime: NSDate){
        guard let sampleType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning) else { return }
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startTime as Date, end: endTime as Date, options: [])
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)

        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: 10000, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor])
        { (query, results, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("An error has occured with the following description: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for r in results! {
                    let result = r as! HKQuantitySample
                    let quantity = result.quantity
                    let count = quantity.doubleValue(for: .meter())
                    self.counts = self.counts + count
                    print(String(format: "sample: %.1f", count))


                }
            }
            print(self.counts)
        }
        healthManager.execute(query)

    }
```

I would like to just get the distance result only from my watch, or better yet eliminate the data that is redundant.

Comment: You should have a field "sourceName". My sample data has sourceName="JPhone". Can you filter by that?

Comment: Would it be appropriate for your watchOS app to be running an HKWorkoutSession? From there I think you could strictly sample distance walking and running from only the watch during the workout.